# Forecasting binary time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, binary-data

I have a binary time series with 1 when the car is not moving, and 0 when the car is moving. I want to make a forecast for a time horizon up to 36 hours ahead and for each hour.

My first approach was to use a Naive Bayes using the following inputs: t-24 (daily seasonal), t-48 (weekly seasonal), hour of the day. However, the results are not very good.

Which articles or software do you recommend for this problem?

Comment: see if this helps
http://www.math.bme.hu/~morvai/publications/papers/MorvaiWeissActApplMath2003ARX.pdf good day

Comment: Have you considered a hidden markov model?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But there is any software package already available with some implementations? I have searched in R, but I only found the VLMC package. Thanks,
Ricardo Bessa

Comment: Ricardo, you should edit your question with this additional information instead of adding it as an answer.  Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Are there really two types of 1's in your data? That is, 1 meaning the car could be moving but is not versus 1 meaning that your car really could not be moving at this time. That would be called one-inflation (it's usually zero-inflation). If so, you need to model when the car can be moving or not versus when it might be moving but is not.

Comment: In this case there is only 1, meaning that the car is not moving. Perhaps hidden markov models can be a good option.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/arima-for-classification-with-soft-labels-29f3109d9840

Answer (score 9):

You can use generalized ARMA (GLARMA) models. See, for example, Kedem and Fokianos (2002), Regression Models for Time Series Analysis.

See also R package glarma (on CRAN)

Comment: This answer should not have been downvoted.

Answer (score 6):

The R package [bsts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bsts/index.html) allows you to estimate Bayesian structural time series models with binary targets by setting `family = 'logit'`. Note, though, that these models often require longer runs than Gaussian data (e.g., `niter = 10000`).

Answer (score 4):

The Hidden markov model is the sequential version of Naive Bayes.  In naive bayes, you have a label with several possible values (in your case 0/1) and a set of features.  The value for y is selected by modeling p(features | label) * p(label).

In a hidden markov model, a sequence of labels is predicted by modeling p(label | previous label) and P(features | label).

Answer (score 2):

How about using logistic regression with some time lags (daily, weekly) as predictors? (most statistical software packages have logistic regression). It's a bit of shooting in the dark -- can you share the data or a plot?