# Binary estimation using ARMA model?

Tags: time-series, arima, binary-data

### Problem

I am a software developer and I have been studying ARMA methods. Currently, I have a spatiotemporal stream of data and would like to apply ARMA model to it.
I have a binary target (independent variable) comprised of 0 and 1. My problem is that I would like to use ARMA to both detect (classify/estimate) 0 and 1 and then later predict using my stream of data.

### Question

What are the ARMA models that can detect/predict/classify/estimate for boolean output (0 or 1)? Is there a specialized name for such a model given my use case is a binary variable as a target? Are there libraries in python or R that I can further study to help me or a literature?

### Attempts

I have been unsuccessful in answering this question and have done the following:

- Introduction to Time Series by Chatfield
- Maching Learning by Kevin Murphy
- StackExchange and Google

I beg your pardon and assistance given I am not a domain expert in this area. Any clues, comments, suggested texts, software packages, and materials would be extremely valuable in assisting me further.

Comment: Check http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197084/binary-time-series or http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15068/forecasting-binary-time-series

Comment: Great links. Thanks! What is the preferred way to measure ARMA models in statistics for classification/detection performance, fit, error etc. In simple terms, what are the metrics to measure model performance and pick a winner?

Comment: There is a whole field of discrete time series models (good reference is: https://www.crcpress.com/Handbook-of-Discrete-Valued-Time-Series/Davis-Holan-Lund-Ravishanker/p/book/9781466577732 another one is http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471363553.html)

Comment: might also read about the NDARMA(p, q) models (articles by Weiss)

Comment: Thanks the responses. I wish I could have given you all more +rep. :)

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/arima-for-classification-with-soft-labels-29f3109d9840