# Any introductory paper, dealing with 'logistic regression on time series data'

Tags: time-series, logistic, classification, references

#### Question

- **Can you introduce me any academic paper dealing with "logistic regression on time series data"?**
- The difficulty of the academic papers that I want is the introductory level for college sophomores studying statistics. (So not so difficult please)
- I guess the logistic regression on time-series data should be different from cross-sectional data.

Comment: Could you say a little more about the use case you're interested in? I typically don't think of logistic regression as being applicable to time series modeling

Comment: If you want to predict a binary time series, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15068/forecasting-binary-time-series   or search this site!