# Any Model for predicting next outcome in a sequence?

Tags: machine-learning, sequential-pattern-mining

I am wondering if there is any model that could recognize a pattern using only previous outcomes and their order to predict the next outcome. Here's an example of data

Game 1 - Win.
Game 2 - Win.
Game 3 - Loss.
Game 4 - Loss.
Game 5 - Win.
Game 6 - Tie.

And the idea is this continues for thousands of games and the model goes through this data and predicts either Win, Loss, or Tie for game 3001.

Are there any suggestions to look into for this kind of problem?

Comment: What are the games? How are they related?

Comment: Some keywords to look for: ARIMA, HiddenMarkov Models.

Comment: @Tim not any specific game just an example I thought of. Another could be something like Event with outcomes yes, no, maybe

Comment: Are the event independent or dependent? What could be said about dependence?

Comment: If independent, just predict the most common result.

Comment: Could you edit to add more details? Are you asking about time-series models for categorical data? For example, for binary time-series there are some threads that may interest you https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197084/binary-time-series and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15068/forecasting-binary-time-series